# Credit Card Number check is not functioning

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate credit card number from a string. It is working when i ONLY pass in the credit card number without anything else. But when there is just one other character it is not valid. I want to get the number from a string with other characters. Why?

**Works (Only number)**

```
var data = '4283023337565974'
if (/^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)$/.test(data) === true) {
  console.log('Valid Credit Card');
} else {
  console.log('Invalid Credit Card');
}
```

**Doesn't work (With other characters)**

```
var data = '123abc4283023337565974def456'
if (/^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)$/.test(data) === true) {
  console.log('Valid Credit Card');
} else {
  console.log('Invalid Credit Card');
}
```

Comment: Remove the non digit characters, and apply your regex afterwards. If your expression is not _regular_, then regex has a hard time.

Comment: @sodawillow yes, but i have a string with other numbers like the expiration date in front of the credit card number and security code after credit card number like this: `01204283023337565974111` so that doesnt help..

Comment: Merging all of those fields into one String, and then validating them all together kinda seems like it takes away the point of validating

Comment: @Light Isn't RegEx able to find the right number in a string of numbers?

Comment: Yes, but it just seems odd to me to validate Numbers in that manner; Either way, I've updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: regex cannot find the _right number_ :) I guess you have a nice starting point with the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `^` and `$` characters from your Regex - They match for the Start and End of the String respectively

```js
let data = 'abc4283023337565974def'

if (/(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)/.test(data) === true) {
  console.log('Valid Credit Card');
} else {
  console.log('Invalid Credit Card');
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could use [`.replace(/\D/g, '')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove any non-digit Character from your String beforehand

The Regex [`\D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) matches any non-digit character, and `g` is the [global flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags) so it will find and replace all matches

```js
let data = 'abc4283023337565974def'

data = data.replace(/\D/g, '');

if (/^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)$/.test(data) === true) {
  console.log('Valid Credit Card');
} else {
  console.log('Invalid Credit Card');
}
```

Comment: Power of regex ... <3